# Where is the $HOME folder located?

Tags: filesystem, files, .desktop

I read recently that `.desktop` files that are used as desktop shortcuts are placed in the `$HOME/Desktop` directory. Where is this directory?

Also, what does the `$` part mean / do?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`$HOME` is an environment variable that contains the location of your home directory, usually `/home/$USER`. The `$` tells us it's a variable. So assuming your user is called `DevRobot` the `.desktop` files are placed in `/home/DevRobot/Desktop/`.

If you want to know where `$HOME` points to, you can run the following in a terminal.

```
[ajefferiss@localhost ~]$ echo "$HOME"
/home/ajefferiss
```

You can use it to move around the filesystem, for example `cd $HOME` but generally you won't see that because you can use `~/` to represent the current users home directory. Or just run `cd` by itself to move to the home directory.

Comment: Note that `$HOME` also varies user to user.  Some system users have an oddball `$HOME` path not on `/home/...`

Comment: ... for example `/root` for `root`.

Comment: See my edit >:-D same goes for $USER.

Comment: `Or just run cd by itself to move to the home directory`, TIL

Comment: Holy crap, @TomHart, do you know how many times I've typed `cd ~` without realizing I could skip the awkward shift-pinky move?

Comment: Probably similar to the amount of times I've typed `cd ~/`!

Comment: @DigitalChris You could use a better keyboard layout to avoid this.

Comment: @AnotherGoogler the best keyboard layout is the one where you get what is printed on the key when you press it. ;)

Comment: Actually `HOME` is the environment variable. The shell needs you to prepend it with `$` to signify it.

Comment: Guys, you could alias `cd ~` to a command  like `gohome` or something short,too. ( I know it's redundant, just kidding here )

Comment: @DigitalChris by the way `~` [used to be on the same key as HOME key](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34198/85039)

Answer (score 5):

`$HOME` is an environment variable that points to `/home/<username>`.  It is located under `/`, and it  contains the user's files.

For more information you may want to take a look at [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

Comment: There's absolutely no rule that $HOME has to point to `/home/<username>`. Apache on Ubuntu creates a user `www-data` whose $HOME is `/var/www`, e.g.

Comment: @Alex we are talking here in regards to Ubuntu and,  Linux.  :)

Comment: Actually `HOME` is the environment variable. The shell needs you to prepend it with `$` to signify it.

Comment: I was talking about Ubuntu/Linux too, Mitch. `/home/<username>` is a convention, not a requirement. It's easy to add a user whose $HOME is at `/somewhere/entirely/different`.

Comment: I set my $HOME location to something different (another partition from an earlier install) and now can't find it...